# Difference between "instantiated" and "subclass"

Tags: java

I was reading a Java tutorial and it said:

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

what does this mean? I thought one had to instantiate in order to create a subclass? This line has really confused me, any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate:

```
AbstractClass a = new AbstractClass(); //illegal
```

Subclass:

```
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass { ... }
ConcreteClass c = new ConcreteClass(); //legal
```

You must create a new class that extends the abstract class, implement all of the abstract methods, and **then** use that new class.

Note that you can also do this:

```
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass { ... }
AbstractClass a = new ConcreteClass(); //legal
```

Comment: very good, you have restated the authors question. but to provide understanding, you must explain *why* you allowed to instantiate the ConcreteClass and not the AbstractClass.

Comment: You can even use an [Anonymous Class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) to *instantiate* the abstract class (behind the scenes, you're creating an anonymous child of the abstract class).

Comment: @AlexLynch: Odd as it may seem, there is a class of question for which a clarifying restatement really is an answer!

Comment: @TomAnderson while true, i do not feel that this restatement/clarification provides an actual answer to the original question. people other than the OP may read this hoping for a thorough answer.

Comment: @AlexLynch well, his question was "what does instantiate/subclass mean." I answered it. ...

Answer (score 1):

A subclass can get all the properties/methods that its parent class has, whereas, instantiated class is when you make an instance of that parent class in memory.

Answer (score 0):

When you say instantiated it means you would like to create the object of the class. Sub-class is the inheriting child. 
For example,

```
abstract class A{
  //Class A is abstract hence, can not be instantiated. The reason being abstract class provides the layout of how the concrete sub-class should behave. 

   pubic abstract void doSomething();
   //This abstract method doSomething is required to be implemented via all the sub-classes. The sub-class B and C implement this method as required.

}

class B extends A{
   //Class B is subclass of A
  public void doSomething(){ System.out.println("I am class B"); }
}
class C extends A{
   //Class C is subclass of A
  public void doSomething(){ System.out.println("I am class C"); }
}

if you try to do this, it would generate an exception

A a = new A();

But this would work fine.
B b = new B();
or 
A a = new B(); //Note you are not instantiating A, here class A variable is referencing the instance of class B
```